# angular ui tooltip appear wrong position to element

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I am trying to display tooltip for upload and download icons in my page. 
The tool tip displays very off to the element.

Html looks like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="documents in docs" >
    <td >
        <a href="#" >{{documents.document_name}}</a>
        <span tooltip="download" class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'></span>
    </td>
</tr>

<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']);
    myApp.controller('secondTrdCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$position',         function($scope,$http,$position) {
    $scope.docs= [{document_name:"doc1",document_type:"A"},    {document_name:"doc2",document_type:"B"}]
}]);
</script>
```

tooltip appears but it appears almost bottom to the page. Not just next to the download icon.

I cannot post screenshot here as my stackoverflow reputation count is not enough so far.

Answer (score 0):

yet don't know the reason why the position went off. Figured out solution using angular directive and bootstrap [data-toggle="toggle"] way.

```
<span data=toggle='tooltip' tooltip>download</span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']);
    myApp.directive('tooltip', function(){
        return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $(element).hover(function(){
                // on mouseenter
                $(element).tooltip('show');
            }, function(){
                // on mouseleave
                $(element).tooltip('hide');
            });
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```